# Environmental variables array giving different results

Tags: c, arrays, linux

Can you please tell me why is the output not same,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    printf("Address of the array of environment variables: %p\n", (void *)env);
        printf("Address of the first environment variable: %p\n", (void *)(env[0]));


    return 0;
}
```

Is not env and env[0] pointing to the same address.

Output:

```
Address of the array of environment variables: 0x7ffcd47f6288
Address of the first environment variable: 0x7ffcd47f7312
```

Comment: `env[0]`  == `*env`. Which is clearly different to `env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same thing. `env` is the array of pointers to strings, which exists somewhere in memory. `env[0]` is the address of the first string, just like `env[1]` is the address of the second string, which is different to the address of the array where those addresses are stored.

Comment: It is an array, which in `c` is also a pointer. In `c` whether a pointer is an array is only in the way it is used. In this case, `env` is a pointer to a block of memory that holds a sequence of items of the same type (in this case pointers), which constitutes an array.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are not the same, this is a common confusion . `env` is indeed a pointer to the first element of an array, but it is not an array .

Comment: The gcc documentation would beg to differ: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html (which then refers to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access) calls it an array. Unless you are meaning that an "array" is the block of memory, while `env` is only the pointer to it, and not the array itself, in which case I would say that's true, but not particularly helpful

Answer (score 0):

Both should be same , you need to print the address properly , try the following code and see ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av, char *env[])
{
    int i;
    printf("Address of the array of environment variables: %p\n", env);
    printf("Address of the first environment variable: %p\n", &env[0]);
    // env is array of pointers to char *
    // env[0] , env[1] , env[3] and so on and each has its own address which will be different
    // which is like , char *envStrings[3] = { "evn1", "env2", "env3" }  3 - Just for example
    char *testEnv[3] = { "evn1", "env2", "env3" };
    printf("Address of testEnv = %p \n", (void *)testEnv);
    for ( i =0; i < 3; i++ ) {
         printf("testEnv[%d] = %s , address is %p \n", i, testEnv[i], &testEnv[i]);
    }
    printf("address of the env = %p \n", env);
    for (i = 0; env[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("\n%s and address is %p", env[i], &env[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

### output :

```
Address of the array of environment variables: 0x7ffdf1d639b8 --> env
Address of the first environment variable: 0x7ffdf1d639b8
Address of testEnv = 0x7ffdf1d638a0
testEnv[0] = evn1 , address is 0x7ffdf1d638a0
testEnv[1] = env2 , address is 0x7ffdf1d638a8
testEnv[2] = env3 , address is 0x7ffdf1d638b0
address of the env = 0x7ffdf1d639b8

XDG_SESSION_ID=36 and address is 0x7ffdf1d639b8 --> first element
......
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 and address is 0x7ffdf1d63a70
_=./test and address is 0x7ffdf1d63a78
OLDPWD=/home/user and address is 0x7ffdf1d63a80
```